# Monitor single Log File

Tags: bash, log, monitoring

I´m looking for a tool or a skript for monitoring 1 single Log file. I´d like to get a notification via telegram if the log file containes a word I´m passing to it.

My approach:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  tail -f /var/log/named/named.log | while read line
  do
    cat /foo/bar/grepThisWords | while read test

            do case "$line" in *"$test"*)
                   [my TG-Curl Notification with "$test found"] 
               esac
            done
  done
```

I planned to run this skript as a daemon 24/7 but it does not work like i want it to work. When I run it in Shell like ./skript.sh it shows the last logs and sends me notifications. It Works nearly okay, but I couldnt make it a Daemon and running 24/7.

Looking forward for helping answers!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to monitor single files: 
The tool inotifywait does exactly what I needed!

```
inotifywait -e modify /for/bar/file | while read t; do 
 if t ~= *test* 
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the suggestions here to use Telegraf:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160883/monitoring-log-files-using-some-metrics-exporter-prometheus-grafana

I have used [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/) myself for monitoring but not for log monitoring. I understand the Prometheus [Blackbox Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) has some sort of log monitoring capability but I have not used it.